# prevent direct html access to folder containing php scripts

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have php scripts that access mysql. I have them in a folder (SourceFiles). I want to ensure users can't directly point to any of these scripts (and therefore mysql database). I have a login setup that accesses these scripts and it all works, but users can also point directly to the files.

moving the folder to above public_html doesn't work since I can't post to a script outside public_html.

protecting the folder using .htaccess doesn't work since then every user needs to have access to the protected folder.

How can I ensure users can only access the php scripts in that folder via login (which I have currently coded in php).

Comment: You state that you have authentication already implemented. So why can't you simply require a valid user at the beginning of your scripts?

Comment: You can still 'require' them even if they are in a protected folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just place this code at the head of each file:

```
/***************DO NOT ALLOW DIRECT ACCESS************************************/
if ( (strpos( strtolower( $_SERVER[ 'SCRIPT_NAME' ] ), strtolower( basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ) !== FALSE ) { // NOT FALSE if the script's file name is found in the URL 
  header( 'HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden' );
  die( '<h2>Direct access to this page is not allowed.</h2>' );
}
/*****************************************************************************/
```

Comment: Given I got three answers, I find it odd that it was closed as a poor question. I selected this as the answer becuase it deals with the question without having to create my own variable based logic, rather it uses properties of the built in $_SERVER variables.

Comment: Well, to prove **IT IS A REAL QUESTION** is the fact that there are 3 answers, so it's not so ambiguous. Don't get it either.

Comment: ok so -1 for not trying the solution before selecting it.... but I am having issues. since I call some of these php files by making them the action in html forms, the php file name shows up in the URL name, so script A can't call/post-to script B if I put this code in script B. Am I missing something? I need to be able to call my own sripts via forms, just don't want direct access any other way.

Comment: Sure. It does not block any call from another script or html form. It is important to use POST, not GET, though, because the last one shows the query in the browser's address bar. I can't really say if it's suitable for the type of application you are developing, but you can always have the option to unaccept the answer. There is no problem, I understand. The idea is the answer solves your question. If it doesn't, there is no reason to keep it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I personally throw in an extra `POST` or `GET`

```
$protected = ($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : $_POST['p']
if ($protected != 'a') { header('location:blah'); }
```

Have something like that at the top of your protected pages.

[Next Time Use This](http://google.com)

Comment: Why do you suggest using Google, since there is a search engine on Stackoverflow to find similar or identical questions?

Comment: @Jocelyn Because you can Google for tutorials on the subject. Try it on here and you'll just trolls chewing people for being dumb.

Comment: [I really see no need to use Google. Stackoverflow search engine works fine.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+prevent+direct+access+to+folder)

Comment: Obviously not, because when you `Ask Question` it does a search, and still repeated questions come up. Googling, usually leads you to the most popular Stack question already asked.

Comment: So... then people can access your scripts by going to `foo.php?p=a`...

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff I simplified it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it before OOP php.

In your main application entry point:

```
define('ACCESS',1);
```

on all protected scripts:

```
if (!defined(ACCESS)) exit;
```

So if user directly accesses any of your 'protected' files, they won't be executed.

## Edit

I see you have already made login system.....why not just use it then? Store in $_SESSION var that defines if user is allowed to access that script or not.....